# Using LIKE with parameter expression in query

Tags: jasper-reports

I was trying to using the like function in *iReport 4.0.1*. Checked online but none seem to work. 
 
Currently trying to use:

```
where  name  LIKE'%$P!{px_name}%'
```

also tried

```
'%$P{px_name}%'
```

but when running the report it comes up saying 'No document'.

But when using  `where name =$P{px_name}` it works perfectly fine.

Comment: What kind of data source are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where clause will be same as you have used in first step which is :-

```
 where  name  LIKE '%$P!{px_name}%'
```

But as you said report says 'The document has no pages' means the query is returning 0 row so just use the same string in LIKE and run the same query in database. Simplest solution is first run the query in database with LIKE operator , if it returns the rows in database then that should also work in iReport.

Comment: I have the same problem 
WHERE status=1 AND address LIKE '"$P{apartmentName}%'
I get
Error:General Problem:null
@Sharad